# Django Paginator raising TypeError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-pagination

I'm trying to use the django pagination module including in the standard distribution version 1.3.

When attempting to load a page that is currently controlled by pagination, if I do not include ?page= on the uri, it throws a TypeError. I've never had this situation arise before, and do not see any reason for it occurring.

Here's my current view:

```
paginator = Paginator(mails_list, 25) # Shows 25 mails per page

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    mails = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver the first page.
    mails = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results
    mails = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

TypeError:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

The error is being presented from line 3 of the above code:

```
mails = paginator.page(page)
```

Anyone witnessed this error before and/or know how to correct it?

Comment: the exceptions PageNotAnInteger and EmptyPage should not check it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
page = request.GET.get('page')
```

To this:

```
page = request.GET.get('page', '1')
```

The problem is you're getting a parameter that doesn't exist. Indexing using `[]` would result in a `KeyError`, but the `get` method returns `None` if it doesn't exist. The paginator is calling `int(None)`, which fails.

The second parameter to the `get` method is a default to return if the key doesn't exist rather than `None`. I passed `'1'` which `int` should not fail on.

Comment: Works a dream. Thanks for the speedy answer. My concern now is, I had done it exactly as illustrated within the documentation. Why is this not working as it should?

Comment: @Neil: Apparently you're using documentation newer than your Django installation. This was apparently [fixed in revision 16026](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/16026).

Comment: @Neil: If you look at [the documentation for the last stable version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/pagination/), you'll see they provide a default to `get` in their example.

Comment: That would explain a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
get = self.request.GET
page = int(get.get('page'))
```

you must convert string to int
or

```
 page = int(request.GET.get('page'))
```

you can do it. Both of them runs.